# Cannot implement Primefaces chart properly

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, charts, primefaces

I want to implement Primefaces chart. But I fail to set properly the legend of the chart:

[image]

This is the code that I use to construct the chart:

```
<h:form>

    <p:barChart id="basic" value="#{DashboardController.categoryModel}" legendPosition="ne"  
                title="Accounts and Groups" min="0" max="#{DashboardController.chartMaxSize}" style="height:400px"
                shadow="true" barPadding="90" seriesColors="4D94FF, 1975FF, 005CE6, 0047B2" 
                yaxisLabel="Size"/>  
</h:form>
```

The Java Code:

```
private void createCategoryModel() throws SQLException, Exception
    {
        categoryModel = new CartesianChartModel();

        // Active Accounts

        ChartSeries chart = new ChartSeries();
        chart.setLabel("Active Accounts");

        chart.set("Active Accounts", countDBActiveAccounts());

        // Blocked Accounts

        chart.setLabel("Blocked Accounts");

        chart.set("Blocked Accounts", countDBBlockedAccounts());


        // Active Groups

        chart.setLabel("Active Groups");

        chart.set("Active Groups", countDBActiveGroups());


        // Blocked Groups

        chart.setLabel("Blocked Groups");

        chart.set("Blocked Groups", countDBBlockedGroups());

        categoryModel.addSeries(chart);



    }
```

Can you help me to construct properly the chart?

P.S From the code proposed by @Ravi I get this chart:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should be using separate instances of ChartSeries like this

```
private void createCategoryModel() throws SQLException, Exception
{
    categoryModel = new CartesianChartModel();

    // Active Accounts

    ChartSeries actAcc = new ChartSeries();
    actAcc .setLabel("Active Accounts");

    actAcc.set("Active Accounts", countDBActiveAccounts());
    actAcc.set("Blocked Accounts", 0);
    actAcc.set("Active Groups", 0);
    actAcc.set("Blocked Groups", 0);

    // Blocked Accounts

    ChartSeries blocAcc = new ChartSeries();
    blocAcc.setLabel("Blocked Accounts");

    blocAcc.set("Active Accounts", 0);
    blocAcc.set("Blocked Accounts", countDBBlockedAccounts());
    blocAcc.set("Active Groups", 0);
    blocAcc.set("Blocked Groups", 0);


    // Active Groups

    ChartSeries actGrp = new ChartSeries();
    actGrp.setLabel("Active Groups");

    actGrp.set("Active Accounts", 0);
    actGrp.set("Blocked Accounts", 0);
    actGrp.set("Active Groups", countDBActiveGroups());
    actGrp.set("Blocked Groups", 0);


    // Blocked Groups

    ChartSeries blocGrp = new ChartSeries();
    blocGrp.setLabel("Blocked Groups");

    blocGrp.set("Active Accounts", 0);
    blocGrp.set("Blocked Accounts", 0);
    blocGrp.set("Active Groups", 0);
    blocGrp.set("Blocked Groups", countDBBlockedGroups());

    categoryModel.addSeries(actAcc );
    categoryModel.addSeries(blocAcc);
    categoryModel.addSeries(actGrp);
    categoryModel.addSeries(blocGrp);

}
```

Comment: I tested the code that you propose. The names of the columns are not correct - they share one name. I want to name them individually like the first picture.

Comment: @user1285928, I do not know if this is the right way to do it. But I have updated it to meet your requirement. I will post again if I get a better solution than this.